# In Python, how do you append a list to a Dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium, loops

I'm learning Python's Selenium, and I've run into a roadblock trying to scrape a "sales" person's data into a data frame.

When I run this code below, it iterates through pages 1 and page 2 which contain 10 salespeople each, which is great, but the problem is that I only get 10 results.

THE GOAL: To run this code which creates a data frame that brings 20 rows of names.

```
iter=1
while iter<3:
    the_link="https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=sales&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL&page="
    the_link = the_link+str(iter).strip()
    browser.get(the_link)

    desc = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("entity-result__title-text")

    x=0
    name = []
    number_of_connections=[]
    link = []

    #Get Name and NUMBER of connections
    while x < len(desc):
        name_and_deg_aray = desc[x].text.split("\n")
        name.append(name_and_deg_aray[0]) #Don't change 0, it grabs name and puts into array
        number_of_connections.append(name_and_deg_aray[3])
        link.append(browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(name_and_deg_aray[0]).get_attribute("href"))
        x=x+1
    

    # Get JOB Title of sales person
    title=[]
    x=0
    title_aray = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('entity-result__primary-subtitle')
    while x < len(title_aray):
        title.append(title_aray[x].text)
        x=x+1
    
   
    iter=iter+1
    
#create DataFrame 
df=pd.DataFrame({'name': name,'title':title, 'number_of_connections':number_of_connections, 'link':link})
```

Current OUTPUT

```
['name1',
 'name2',
 'name3',
 'name4',
 'name5',
 'name6',
 'name7',
 'name8',
 'name9',
 'name10']
```

IDEAL OUTPUT

```
['name1',
 'name2',
 'name3',
 'name4',
 'name5',
 'name6',
 'name7',
 'name8',
 ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 'name20']
```

Comment: title needs to be outside the loop.Otherwise you just initialize it back to empty each time.

Comment: Thank you so much !! It's working perfectly!

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Thank you so much !! It's working perfectly with your advice !!